# Running liquibase within Java code

Tags: java, liquibase

For some reason there's no documentation on running liquibase inside Java code.  I want to generate tables for Unit tests.

How would I run it directly in Java?

e.g.

```
Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase()
liquibase.runUpdates() ?
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/using-liquibase-directly-from-java ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It should be something like (taken from liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase source):

```
java.sql.Connection c = YOUR_CONNECTION;
Liquibase liquibase = null;
try {
    Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(c))
    liquibase = new Liquibase(YOUR_CHANGELOG, new FileSystemResourceAccessor(), database);
    liquibase.update();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new DatabaseException(e);
} finally {
    if (c != null) {
        try {
            c.rollback();
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //nothing to do
        }
    }
}
```

There are multiple implementation of ResourceAccessor depending on how your changelog files should be found.

Comment: Added to Nathan Answer refer the real code from here https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/integration/servlet/LiquibaseServletListener.java#L209

Answer (score 5):

I found a way to achieve setting up the database using *either* maven or Java. The above example uses `FileSystemResourceAccessor()`, which unfortunately makes it so that if you deploy an application which needs to set up a database from the jar itself, then you end up having to *extract* the jar as a zip as a workaround, since these liquibase files exist only in the jar. This means your jar ultimately isn't portable, and you have to have `maven` wherever you want to set up the database.

Use this structure:

`src/main/resources/liquibase/db.changelog-master.xml`
`src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogs/...`

Your DB changelog master can look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <!-- <includeAll path="src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogs"/> -->
    <include file="changelogs/my-date.1.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

You can use this section for your `pom.xml`, in order to make sure `mvn install` will also set up your liquibase DB.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
   <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.5.1</version>
   <configuration>
      <changeLogFile>liquibase/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
      <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
      <url>${jdbc.url}</url>
      <username>${jdbc.username}</username>
      <password>${jdbc.password}</password>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <phase>process-resources</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>update</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Use `ClassLoaderResourceAccessor()` instead of `FileSystemResourceAccessor()`.

```
public static void runLiquibase() {

    Liquibase liquibase = null;
    Connection c = null;
    try {
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(DataSources.PROPERTIES.getProperty("jdbc.url"),
                DataSources.PROPERTIES.getProperty("jdbc.username"),
                DataSources.PROPERTIES.getProperty("jdbc.password"));

        Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(c));
        log.info(DataSources.CHANGELOG_MASTER);
        liquibase = new Liquibase(DataSources.CHANGELOG_MASTER, new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
        liquibase.update("main");
    } catch (SQLException | LiquibaseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new NoSuchElementException(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (c != null) {
            try {
                c.rollback();
                c.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                //nothing to do
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might need full path here: `<changeLogFile>liquibase/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>`
Hence: `src/main/resources/liquibase/db.changelog-master.xml`

Comment: where is coming this DataSources.PROPERTIES and DataSources.CHANGELOG_MASTER ?

Answer (score 2):

You can practice with h2-database in test(path "db/changelog.xml" is main/resources/db/changelog.xml):

```
import liquibase.Contexts;
import liquibase.Liquibase;
import liquibase.database.Database;
import liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory;
import liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection;
import liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException;
import liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class LiquidBaseTest {

    @Test
    public void testExecuteLiquidBaseScripts() throws SQLException, LiquibaseException {
        java.sql.Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:");

        try {
            Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
            Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("db/changelog.xml", new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
            liquibase.update(new Contexts());
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.rollback();
                connection.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void runLiquibase() throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

    Scope.child(config, () -> {
        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("your database connection url");
            Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
            Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase("database/db.changelog-main.xml", new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
            liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });

}
```

This code will help you to manage a multiple changelogs based on the version and you can provide a reference of main file.

I have followed structure as below.

- src/main/resources/database/db.changelog-main.xml
- src/main/resources/database/changelogs/db.changelog-v-1.0.0.xml
- src/main/resources/database/changelogs/db.changelog-v-1.0.1.xml

A reference link https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/using-liquibase-java-api.html